# Do all variables in the loss function have to be tensor with grads in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I have the following function

```py
def msfe(ys, ts):
    ys=ys.detach().numpy() #output from the network
    ts=ts.detach().numpy() #Target (true labels)
    pred_class = (ys>=0.5) 
    n_0 = sum(ts==0) #Number of true negatives
    n_1 = sum(ts==1) #Number of true positives
    FPE = sum((ts==0)[[bool(p) for p in (pred_class==1)]])/n_0 #False positive error
    FNE = sum((ts==1)[[bool(p) for p in (pred_class==0)]])/n_1 #False negative error
    loss= FPE**2+FNE**2

    loss=torch.tensor(loss,dtype=torch.float64,requires_grad=True)


    return loss
```

and I wonder, if the autograd in Pytorch works properly, since `ys` and `ts` does not have the `grad` flag.

So my question is: do all the variables (`FPE,FNE,ys,ts,n_1,n_0`) have to be tensors, before `optimizer.step()` works, or is it okay that it is only the final function (`loss`) which is ?

Comment: Hope this helps! Based on my understanding of Tensorflow - from TensorFlow's point of view, everything is a tensor. Variables(number/floats) are tensor of shape (1,1). So, Yes they have to be tensor and `tensor` is the only datatype it knows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the variables you want to optimise via `optimizer.step()` need to have gradient.

In your case it would be `y` predicted by network, so you shouldn't `detach` it (from graph).

Usually you don't change your `targets`, so those don't need gradients. You shouldn't have to `detach` them though, tensors by default don't require gradient and won't be backpropagated.

`Loss` will have gradient if it's ingredients (at least one) have gradient.

Overall you rarely need to take care of it manually.

BTW. **don't** use `numpy` with PyTorch, there is rarely ever the case to do so. You can perform most of the operations you can do on `numpy` array on PyTorch's tensor.

BTW2. There is no such thing as `Variable` in `pytorch` anymore, only tensors which require gradient and those that don't.

## Non-differentiability

### 1.1 Problems with existing code

Indeed, you are using functions which are not differentiable (namely `>=` and `==`). Those will give you trouble only in the case of your outputs, as those required gradient (you can use `==` and `>=` for `targets` though).

Below I have attached your loss function and outlined problems in it in the comments:

```
# Gradient can't propagate if you detach and work in another framework
# Most Python constructs should be fine, detaching will ruin it though.
def msfe(outputs, targets):
    # outputs=outputs.detach().numpy() # Do not detach, no need to do that
    # targets=targets.detach().numpy() # No need for numpy either
    pred_class = outputs >= 0.5  # This one is non-differentiable
    # n_0 = sum(targets==0) # Do not use sum, there is pytorch function for that
    # n_1 = sum(targets==1)

    n_0 = torch.sum(targets == 0)  # Those are not differentiable, but...
    n_1 = torch.sum(targets == 1)  # It does not matter as those are targets

    # FPE = sum((targets==0)[[bool(p) for p in (pred_class==1)]])/n_0 # Do not use Python bools
    # FNE = sum((targets==1)[[bool(p) for p in (pred_class==0)]])/n_1 # Stay within PyTorch
    # Those two below are non-differentiable due to == sign as well
    FPE = torch.sum((targets == 0.0) * (pred_class == 1.0)).float() / n_0
    FNE = torch.sum((targets == 1.0) * (pred_class == 0.0)).float() / n_1
    # This is obviously fine
    loss = FPE ** 2 + FNE ** 2

    # Loss should be a tensor already, don't do things like that
    # Gradient will not be propagated, you will have a new tensor
    # Always returning gradient of `1` and that's all
    # loss = torch.tensor(loss, dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)

    return loss
```

### 1.2 Possible solution

So, you need to get rid of 3 non-differentiable parts. You could in principle try to approximate it with continuous outputs from your network (provided you are using `sigmoid` as activation). Here is my take:

```
def msfe_approximation(outputs, targets):
    n_0 = torch.sum(targets == 0)  # Gradient does not flow through it, it's okay
    n_1 = torch.sum(targets == 1)  # Same as above
    FPE = torch.sum((targets == 0) * outputs).float() / n_0
    FNE = torch.sum((targets == 1) * (1 - outputs)).float() / n_1

    return FPE ** 2 + FNE ** 2
```

Notice that to minimize `FPE` `outputs` will try to be `zero` on the indices where `targets` are zero. Similarly for `FNE`, if targets are `1`, network will try to output `1` as well.

Notice similarity of this idea to [BCELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) (Binary CrossEntropy).

And lastly, example you can run this on, just for sanity check:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(30, 100),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(100, 200),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(200, 1),
        torch.nn.Sigmoid(),
    )
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    targets = torch.randint(high=2, size=(64, 1)) # random targets
    inputs = torch.rand(64, 30) # random data
    for _ in range(1000):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = msfe_approximation(outputs, targets)
        print(loss)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(((model(inputs) >= 0.5) == targets).float().mean())
```

Comment: If I use only torch.<function> for all the calculations above, `loss` is just a tensor with no gradient. Can you still slice and keep the gradient? I struggle a bit with the `ts=1` but `pred_class=0` - seems like it is the part which breaks

Comment: Expanded my answer about non-differentiability issues and possible solution if you want to keep similar function to the one you've provided. BTW. Slicing works in PyTorch (as opposed to `>=` and `==`) as it's just getting certain values from tensors in slice defined way, it's not breaking the gradient calculations.